# python string encoding issue on dealing with accentuation

Tags: python, encoding

I have  python script that prints a string `value` with an incorrect encoding. I've tried setting a string `s` with the same string as the `value` and it print fine. I've print also their type and they both are `strings`. 
This is what the code looks like:

```
s = "\xC3\xBA"
print s
print type(s)

print value
print type(value)
```

and This is the output:

```
ú
<type 'str'>
\xC3\xAD
<type 'str'>
```

the value output should be `ú`instead of `\xC3\xAD` . How come when I set the `s` string to `\xC3\xAD` it is printed correctly?!  Does anyone have an idea?

The `value` is set this way:

```
apps = data.split('-') 
for app in apps:
    app_data = app.split('\n')
    app_new = {}
    for app_field in app_data:
        key_value = app_field.split(':')
        if len(key_value) == 2:
            key = key_value[0].lstrip().rstrip().lower()
            value = key_value[1].lstrip().rstrip()
```

Comment: You're hiding the code that sets `value`. Please show it.

Comment: Its kind of tricky the part that sets it, but isn`t there a way I can force the output to be the same as the `s` one ?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your backslashes somehow got escaped as well:

```
In [1]: value = "\\xC3\\xBA"

In [2]: print value
\xC3\xBA

In [3]: type(value)
Out[3]: <type 'str'>
```